# Fancybox returns "The requested content cannot be loaded." in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox-2

I'm having an issue with Fancybox (v2.1.5). I want to open a "Wait, please" dialog while generating pdf export:

```
function ShowLoading(token, message) {
        $.fancybox({
            'href': 'path/to/MVC/controller',
            'type': 'ajax',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'showCloseButton': false,
            'modal': true,
            'enableEscapeButton': false,
            'closeClick': false,
            'beforeShow': function () {
                $(".popup-loading-message").text(message);
            },
            helpers:
                {
                    overlay: { closeClick: false } 
                }
        });
....
}
```

href points to MVC controller method, that returns nothing more than this:

```
<div class="popup-loading">
    <div class="popup-loading-content">
        <div class="popup-loading-graphics"><i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw"></i></div>
        <div class="popup-loading-message"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

All works perfectly in Chrome or IE but not in Firefox, where I get "The requested content cannot be loaded." error message. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, this is the trick:

```
function ShowLoading(token, message) {
   setTimeout(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'href': 'path/to/MVC/controller',
            'type': 'ajax',
            'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
            'showCloseButton': false,
            'modal': true,
            'enableEscapeButton': false,
            'closeClick': false,
            'beforeShow': function () {
                $(".popup-loading-message").text(message);
            },
            helpers:
                {
                    overlay: { closeClick: false } 
                }
        });
    ....
    });
}
```

Don't ask why... ;o)